# Define method with object instantiation in java

Tags: java

I'm slowly transitioning from C++ to java and I do not understand the following piece of code:

```
public class TestThread 
{
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        Thread t = new MyThreads() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                System.out.println(" foo");
            }
        };
        t.start();
        System.out.println("out of run");
    }
}
```

An object type "MyThreads" is being instantiated, but what does the function "void run" mean?

Why is it written using that syntax right after the object instantiation?

Is that function being overriden?

When is this kind of syntax (where I define a function with an object instantiation) necessary/required? and where is it preferred/useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the class `MyThreads` either require you to first write a method with name run or the way you are doing provides the ability to change the existing run method behaviour where you are declaring.

It is like overriding if run method is already there or creating the method when you want to create object.

This provides the ability to create objects of `MyThreads` without having to change the original class or creating multiple classes.

```
public class TestThread 
{
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        Thread t = new MyThreads() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                System.out.println(" foo");
            }
        };
        t.start();

        Thread t1 = new MyThreads() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                System.out.println(" this time it is somethidn else");
            }
        };
        t1.start();

        System.out.println("out of run");
    }
}
```

Little modification to your code shows the advantage of having this feature. If you observe run method of t1 is doing something different than what is in t. So it is now completely new thread.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to define a new function this way that didn't exist in the parent class? I would expect it to be possible if this is a subclass, but i get a compile error

Answer (score 0):

This code is equivalent to

```
public class TestThread 
{
    static class MyThreadSubclass extends MyClass {
       public void run() {
         System.out.println("foo");
       }
    }
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        Thread t = new MyThreadSubclass();
        t.start();
        System.out.println("out of run");
    }
}
```

It's just a convenient way of defining a subclass inline, without having to give it a name; it's just syntactic sugar.  It's creating an object of a subclass that overrides the method `run()` from `MyThreads`.

Comment: Also worth noting that the run method is what is actually run (funnily enough) when you create the new thread by calling start(). If you were to call the run() method directly instead of start(), it would not run as a separate thread.

Comment: So the class Thread already has a method called run() and I'm just overriding it. What if there was no method called run and I want to add it. In this case I get a compile error...